# Switch workspace animation lag (with screen recording)

Tags: macos, keyboard, screen, mission-control, accessibility

Both my Macbook and Mac are suffering from a disturbing lag, right after workspace animation finishes the window gets its focus a split second late. During the time, the OS ignores any input, so one have to wait until this lag is over. For those who change workspaces rapidly, this is a huge workflow problem.

I recorded a short screencast of the problem with two Terminal windows running on two workspaces. But the behavior is the same for any app (e.g. Finder), inability to take any inputs shortly after animation is frustrating:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aD9k3nBOj30

When I set Preferences - Accessibility - Screen - Reduce Motion the animation changes form movement to fade, however, the lag is still there. I noticed this in Monterey and Ventura, perhaps this bug is there for a longer period of time.

It almost looks like the animation has slow start and ending which creates the lag feeling. But with the Reduce Motion function, I would expect it to be snappier or something.

In older versions of MacOS, it was possible to change the animation speed with a setting (via `defaults` command). This no longer works.  Still, having uses trying to find a workaround does likely mean that this feature would benefit from review and rework.

This is Macbook Pro 16 (M1/32GB RAM) running MacOS Ventura 16.1 with default settings. Looks like disabling or enabling ProMotion have no effect on this lag. I tested this also on Mac Mini M1 16GB RAM with LG WideScreen (75Hz/60Hz) display with the same result.

Do you see the same? Which MacOS version?

Any known workaround for this issue?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Filed Apple Feedback no. FB11744085 for the record.